# TouchableHighlight blocks child events (drag events)

Tags: react-native, touch-event

React Native :

```
import {TouchableHighlight, View} from "react-native";

 <TouchableHighlight
        underlayColor="transparent"
        onPress={this.handleSingleAndDoubleClick}
        disabled={false}
      >
          {this.props.children}
      </TouchableHighlight>
```

Having the above code, the children of the TouchableHighlight has a iframe (canvas) that responds to drag, pinch , zoom gestures. When the TouchableHighlight is disabled using the **disabled={true} , the gesture works fine**. But when **TouchableHighlight is not disabled**, only the **onPress** event is triggered other events are ignored. How make it so that both the events are respected i.e onPress to picked up by TouchableHighlight and other events such as drag, pinch, zoom gestures to not be blocked / ignored.

*What I have tried :*

```
 <TouchableHighlight
        underlayColor="transparent"
        onPress={this.handleSingleAndDoubleClick}
        style={{ ...(this.props.style || {}) }}
        disabled={false}
      >
        <View onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          {this.props.children}
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
```

With the above implementation touch events drag, pinch , zoom works but the **TouchableHighlight** onPress event is **not** fired when pressed.

Thanks

Comment: check your import of TouchableHighlight

Comment: @Kishan using TouchableHighlight from react-native i.e(import {TouchableHighlight, View} from "react-native";) , updated the question to add this line as well.

Comment: import { TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';